Sort questions by FAQ?
I am confused what the sort criteria is when selecting FAQ on the main questions link:
http://f.cl.ly/items/3V0K1u3R3F0P2L0P380n/Screen%20Shot%202011-09-07%20at%2012.51.26%20PM.png
Do we eventually get to add those manually? It says they are sorted by "number of links" - what does that mean? Also why does it include closed questions?

Choose one of those FAQ questions, and have a look at the number of “linked“ questions on the side column, on the right (above “Related“ questions).
‘FAQ sort’ will display questions with the highest number of “linked (to)” questions first.

links to or links from? seems like a fairly useless and confusing sort filter, especially as it is separate from the site FAQ itself

thanks - well defer to yr wisdom here
